# Create web service from wsdl is missing in file types in Netbeans

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans

I want to create WEB Service from existing WSDL, but there is no such field as "Create WS from WSDL".

How can I add it to file types?

Answer (score 0):

In an earlier release of NetBeans you could [create a web service directly from a WSDL file](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-7006/ghyto/index.html), but for some reason the approach is different, and less obvious, now:

1. Create a simple web application using the wizard: **File > New Project > Java Web > Web Application**.
2. In the **Projects** panel select the node of that project, right click and select **New > Web Service from WSDL...** from the dropdown menu:

[image: menuSelection]

3. In the **New Web Service from WSDL** dialog there is a field named **Select Local WSDL File or Enter WSDL URL** where you specify the WSDL file to be imported.

[image: importWsdlDialog]